# Create a stored procedure to iterate through a list of tables and truncate them in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm debating whether or not to try running through a list of tables and truncating them with a stored procedure. Would it be that easy with MySql and how would I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I truncate all tables from a MySQL Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756430/how-can-i-truncate-all-tables-from-a-mysql-database)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I think that's different. He's using the information schema to collect all tables in a database and then truncate them. I only want to truncate select tables, as defined in a list. For me the answer giving in that question would be a horrible fix!

Comment: That is the way to get a list of tables -- SHOW TABLES is a synonym, and there're countless similar questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+truncate+tables

Comment: Yes, but can you define a list of tables as a variable or take in a list as an argument for the stored procedure? I'm sorry, but none of those answers really contain what I'm looking for.

Comment: Now that you've clarified why the answer wouldn't work, if a parameter & it's incorporation is too difficult...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main piece of info you need is the list of tables.  Most platforms support this:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables
```

However, before you code the sproc, do a select * from information_schema.tables and examine the entries, there may be some you do not expect -- system tables and such, so you may need to craft a filter to get the set you want.

Since I don't do mySQL that much, I can't show you the code, but if you can translate this from MS SQL, and fill in some blanks you can make it work:

```
declare @table_name varchar(200)
while 1=1 begin
    select top 1 @table_name = table_name
      from information_schema.tables
     where ....possible filter...
    if @table_name is null break

    -- for this line you may need dynamic sql
    truncate table @table_name
end
```

Comment: That's SQL Server, not MySQL syntax

Comment: @OMG Ponies, hence the line in the answer: "ince I don't do mySQL that much, I can't show you the code but if you can translate this from MS SQL, and fill in some blanks you can make it work:"